# Struggling to find an error in python

Tags: python

I'm making a birthday present for my friend. I am making a database of every single Marvel Character ever and I have done two of them so far, went to test it and it says error. I have looked all over the code and I have tried a lot but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is the code.

```
    from time import sleep

print ("Welcome to the Marvel Database please input the name of a marvel character you want to research. Please make sure you type the name as accurately as possible.")
character = input()

if character == 'A-Bomb':
    print ("loading", sleep(.5), ".", sleep(.5), ".", sleep(.5), ".")
    print ("Character found.")
    sleep(.5)
    print ("Name is A-Bomb.")
    sleep(1)
    print ("Unknown if they or it are Hero or Villan.")
    sleep(1)
    print ("No infomation found.")
    sleep(1)

elif character == 'a-bomb':
    print ("loading", sleep(.5), ".", sleep(.5), ".", sleep(.5), ".")
    print ("Character found.")
    sleep(.5)
    print ("Name is A-Bomb")
    sleep(1)
    print ("Unknown if they or it are Hero or Villan.")
    sleep(1)
    print ("No infomation found")
    sleep(1)

elif character == 'a bomb':
    print ("loading", sleep(.5), ".", sleep(.5), ".", sleep(.5), ".")
    print ("Character found.")
    sleep(.5)
    print ("Name is A-Bomb")
    sleep(1)
    print ("Unknown if they or it are Hero or Villan.")
    sleep(1)
    print ("No infomation found")
    sleep(1)

elif character == 'A-bomb':
    print ("loading", sleep(.5), ".", sleep(.5), ".", sleep(.5), ".")
    print ("Character found.")
    sleep(.5)
    print ("Name is A-Bomb")
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You need to highlight your code and use the `{}` button in the future.

Comment: `print(sleep(0.5))` will print the return value of `time.sleep()`, which is always `None`. And remember that `sleep()` will be evaluated before the `print()`, so the triple-sleep print is more or less equal to `sleep(1.5); print(...)`.

Comment: @dhke I think the point of the intermittent sleep(.5) was to simulate a loading animation

Comment: you can reduce the length of your code by using Python's `lower()` function

Comment: Also if you want to make a database application, you should probably use an actual database to store the information (e.g.: SQLite). And try to avoid copy pasting the same code/information over and over again

Comment: You could save a ridiculous amount of checking for each hyphenation or capitalization of the name by just checking `if character.replace('-', ' ').lower() == 'a bomb':` and having a single block to handle it, not four identical blocks with slightly different tests.

Comment: 1) If you are using Python2 use `raw_input()`, not `input()` 2) If the indentation were fixed on the first line, this runs fine.

Comment: @smoggers is definitely correct. You could even make a small function that uses lower() and gets rid of complicating characters (" ", "-", "'" etc), so that it's much more robust. And/or make it look to see whether it's in a set of names. eg. if character.lower().strip().replace("-","") in set(["abomb","abob","abom"]):

Comment: @sudobangbang Yeah, I know, but it doesn't do that as implemented ;-).

Comment: A database is probably overkill, but you should at least read up on dictionaries. Create a dictionary whose keys are the characters and whose values are the information such as villain status that you want to return.

Comment: @JohnColeman there's [a lot of marvel characters](http://marvel.com/comics/characters). If OP really wants to create a full list containing all of them + detailed bio then I don't think a DB is overkill :)

Comment: @UnholySheep Good point, but given what OP is currently trying to do, and where they seem to be at in learning Python (or any programming), I think that a DB is overkill. This seems to be a first program, so starting out with dictionaries before learning about databases would make sense. They will likely be forced to scale back some of their ambitions to a smaller set of major characters. Perhaps they could set a goal of giving a version 2 with a snazzy GUI as a follow-up gift in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
from time import sleep

print ("Welcome to the Marvel Database please input the name of a marvel character you want to research. Please make sure you type the name as accurately as possible.")
character = input().lower()

a_bomb_list = ["a-bomb", "a bomb"]

if character in a_bomb_list:
    print ("loading", sleep(.5), ".", sleep(.5), ".", sleep(.5), ".")
    print ("Character found.")
    sleep(.5)
    print ("Name is A-Bomb.")
    sleep(1)
    print ("Unknown if they or it are Hero or Villan.")
    sleep(1)
    print ("No infomation found.")
    sleep(1)
```

You do not need to create a separate `if` for each permutation, the above code works with any capitalization of "a-bomb" or "a bomb" :)